# Why am I getting call to undefined function after splitting module functions to two files?

Tags: 7, testing

Now my module has two main files:

- menu_perm.module
- menu_perm.admin.inc

I added second file to .info:

> files[] = menu_perm.admin.inc

I cleared the cache.

In my test class (PHPUnit) file I am bootrapping Drupal by:

```
drupal_bootstrap(DRUPAL_BOOTSTRAP_FULL);
```

and I call form submit function manually inside test function, ends with below error:

> Call to undefined function menu_perm_user_form_submit()

Function is in menu_perm.admin.inc.

Before this everything was ok.

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 3):

`files[]` only works for class/interface autoloading, it won't include arbitrary PHP files. The docs say

> Drupal now supports a dynamic-loading code registry. To support it, all modules must now declare any code files containing class or interface declarations in the .info file

You can get around it by adding a line like this to the top of your .module file:

```
require_once DRUPAL_ROOT . '/sites/all/modules/my_module/my_module.admin.inc';
```

Comment: I would rather use __DIR__ instead of an absolute path. As long as you are within the same module and not within a hook implementation, this is the safest way to do it.

Answer (score -1):

Use module_load_include inside your test function, e.g.
    module_load_include('inc', 'my_module', 'my_module.admin');